# SQL Windows Authentication Roles?

Tags: sql, windows-authentication, roles

I have read a lot, but still i can't find the point that i want which is the following:

If i can connect to sql via windows authentication mode, then that mean after i install my software with it's database the user can easily look and manipulate my database, and if i want to revoke any role i will be limiting my program when it's going to access the database.

Is there a way to limit the user access on the database while my program can have a full access without any problems.

Comment: Have different users with different access rules.

Comment: it's windows authentication so it's only one user.

Comment: Windows authentication doesn't mean you only have to have one user.

Comment: That assuming that there is more than one user on the machine, but what if there is only one user and it's an admin (Full Access) ?

Comment: If it's admin, it can create new users with lower privileges.

Comment: I know that but is there another way to do it without creating another user account, and if i created another user with low privileges that means that the user have to access the software from that user account .

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5171/discussion-between-user733659-and-oded)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The application doesn't have to login to sql using the account that it's being run from.  So create a seperate user account for the application that has all the rights it needs and login using that account from the application.

Alternatively, you can just setup a seperate login using sql server authentication and then you won't need another user account.

If this isn't your application and you can't modify it to use a different account to login with, then you could run the application itself under another account.  When you hold shift and right click an icon you'll see it gives you an option to do so.  However, I don't know how you would set the application up to automatically run that way without the user having to know the password to type in.  I think it's possible though.

Also, I think when you set the account up you can set it as a special type that users can't actually login with.  So they could know the password to it to run the application, but they wouldn't be able to actually login under that account to do anything with it.  This wouldn't prevent someone smart enough from gaining access, but it's a good safeguard.

Comment: the sql connects by default using the current user account, how can i login using another account then ?

Comment: I was assuming that you are developing this application.  If that's not the case then I don't know.  If you are, then how are you currently connecting?

Comment: i have done what everyone here told me not to, i have dropped all roles on windows authentication and changed it to mixed mode and granted full access to "sa" user in sql authentication mode, so this will make it impossible for the user to access that database until he knows what the password is.

Comment: I edited my answer to provide another alternative.  However, if you're not in a corporate environment that places restrictions on you being able to use mixed mode then I would recommend just doing that for convenience sake.  Just make sure you have a strong enough password and that it's not on a server that can be reached over the internet (or if it is at least use a non standard port).

Comment: +1 to the alternative. Create an account for the app to use and you won't need further authentication -> works best if you're in a corporate environment where only domain-accounts will be able to log into the machines, and to allow windows authentication in your set up would mean that you'll have to add maintenance to make sure that the roles are properly set --which can be a waste of time especially in production databases. You can use the user's windows auth (through the app) to verify other information from active directory instead. :)